# Is there any way to write compressed video data to a buffer instead of a file using VFW?

Tags: c++, vfw

I've got a program which uses the (deprecated) VFW API for recording the screen. 
In order to capture the screen without saving the results, the program takes about 600-700 ms / 100 frames. However, calling the AVIStreamWrite () function increases this to ~2000 ms, and I suspect it's because of saving to the harddisk directly. So I'd like to save all video data to a RAM buffer instead of a file and save it later to the harddisk.
I also tried using the IC functions instead, however I've encountered other difficulties with those.
**Is there any way to make the AVIStreamWrite () function write to a buffer instead of a file?**

Some simplified code (I'll add the function arguments and develop the code if required):

```
bool record=1;
AVIFileInit();
//Initial stream and bitmap header declaration
AVIFileOpen();
//Declaration of compressed stream and of its parameters
AVIMakeCompressedStream();
AVIStreamSetFormat();
while(record) //main loop
{
      //FPS stabilization
      //Screen capturing below, takes about 6 ms per frame
      BitBlt();
      GetDIBits ();
      //Frame saving and compressing below, takes about 14 ms per frame 
      AVIStreamWrite();
      //Something that breaks the main loop
}
//clean-up
```

Comment: The quick and dirty solution is to write to a ramdisk. /dev/shm on most linux systems is usually directly mapped to memory so I would try writing there.

Comment: @Lalaland I believe the specific API OP is referring to is a Windows server API.

Comment: @Mansoor Indeed, it's a Windows API. Not necessarily Windows server though.

Comment: To your question, `AVIStreamWrite` takes argument `lpbuffer`, why not use this directly, or copy it into another buffer?

Comment: @Mansoor Because it's too big. Each frame has about 5 MB, meaning that 7 seconds of recording at 30 FPS would fill up 1 GB.

Comment: So maybe copy to an in-memory buffer, and when you reach some limit, then print to disk? As opposed to constantly hitting the disk.

Comment: @Mansoor I tried a ring buffer with multi-threading, but the screen capture thread caught up too quickly to the encoder thread, rendering it not too useful. Also, the API doesn't support encoding multiple frames in one call...